# Этимология уплетать

Tags: этимология

Этимология слова "уплетать" в значении "быстро есть". В словаре Даля прочёл, что это слово значит "увивать,покрывать плетением". Связанны ли эти значения, и какая этимология?

Comment: Читай внимательнее: * Жадно есть, пожирать, много или спешно есть, оплетать. -ся, страд. ...| оплетала, жадный едок и обжора.
 https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc2p/368850

Comment: В смысле быстро использовать, расходовать?  Уплел всю пряжу? Метафорично!

Comment: @Sharon каламбурно.